# Roslyn getting details under {SomeSyntax}.Type

Tags: c#, roslyn

[image: debug]

I have a generic class:

```
public class NestedDict<T>: Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, T> { }
```

As shown in the picture, I can parse and access its `BaseList` and find out its `TypeArgumentList` is sitting there in debugger. However, I can not simply call `baseType.Type.TypeArgumentList` to access it, because it is not a public member that I can access.

Normally, what is the correct way to access the `TypeArgumentList` under `Type` in my case? or any Type details in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might know that `baseType` is a generic type (So a `GenericNameSyntax`), it isn't the only possible case so the objects in `BaseList` are of a parent type (`TypeSyntax`).

You only have to cast to access the `TypeArgumentList` :

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("public class NestedDict<T>: Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, T> { } ");
var cu = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var c = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)cu.ChildNodes().Single();

var baseDeclaration = (BaseTypeSyntax)c.BaseList.ChildNodes().Single();
var baseNameSyntax = (GenericNameSyntax)baseDeclaration.Type;
Console.WriteLine(baseNameSyntax.TypeArgumentList.Arguments[0].ToFullString());
Console.WriteLine(baseNameSyntax.TypeArgumentList.Arguments[1].ToFullString());
```